# Error message in while create group facebook

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I want to create a group by my facebook application by the code; :

```
Dim fb As New FacebookClient("CAAFzn8dpP6IBAGFs2LwqXQLpf06rR000z3NEpuzr4vakG0raFuwkV3hzXge3sLv2bLpQNAnK3iFJaag2nFXRM8ug6qa3cQC2wRvvcjWUUehz5zb42fZCN6MFZCCVfxJf9eL9V9DaUhrNF8uycgW5WF4IUwdBfZAKF8ZAnt")

        Dim params As Object = New ExpandoObject()
        params.name = "test Me"
        Await fb.PostTaskAsync("/4086005059268514/groups", params)
```

return same `error "(OAuthException - #15) (#15)` This method must be called with an app access_token."

Comment: I added the code " params.access_token = "CAAFzn8dpP6IBAEmukSMa9wT2dkCQVZAfCn20uzpOim86pP83M1mf2E1ttlTVZB3wTP45ZCcCkTbJmvWCZCv424ShjzBKnpsEiMx7npGhE6wnInH7DR8r5NrowFGWAn11ApaUAiGKtRtCZAG4141414141y8lMlIoaIyiQG6qaLvAR66zEoNnpMvgVDppZBsUnT8S84lsIgLNN"
but not work

Comment: And – _is_ that an _app_ access token?